# htaccess Allow only internal IP

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=173.220.70.101 [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=173.220.70.102
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would like to have a or statement for two IP address

the old version worked for one IP
not sure why this isn't working anymore.

Comment: `x != A OR x != B` will _always_ be true. You want `AND` instead of `OR`. When using multiple [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), the `AND` is implicit. You don't spell it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=173.220.70.101
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=173.220.70.102
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Without [OR]...

Answer (score 0):

Allowing only 173.220.70.1 and 173.220.70.2

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^173.220.70.[1-2]$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```

Allowing any IP except 173.220.70.1 and 173.220.70.2

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^173.220.70.[1-2]$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```